# Stripe Checkout One-Time Payments - Billing Portal does not show payment history/invoices

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Stripe and Billing Portal.

If the user subscribes to a plan - after successful payment `invoice.paid` webhook event is triggered and it can be used to know if the payment was completed successfully. Also, when user visits Billing Portal - he can see that payment under "Payments history" and view/download PDF invoices.

However, if it's a one-time payment, once when user pays - he just gets redirected back (to the specified `success_url` and I receive `checkout.session.completed` webhook which, I guess, is the only way to really know if the payment was really successful (because, for one-time payments, Stripe does not send `invoice.paid` webhook).

The problem is that, after successful one-time payment, on Billing Portal user cannot see it under "Payment history" nor there's invoice for that payment.

I was checking the documentation and I couldn't find anything/any configuration option that would enable showing one-time payments and their invoices under "Payment history" on Billing Portal.

Is there such option, or one-time payments simply cannot appear under "Payment history"/users cannot see invoices for one-time payments on Billing Portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Invoice objects are created with one-time payments and any receipts relating to one-time payments are not accessible via the Billing Portal. This is not configurable currently!

Comment: Ok. So this means that Stripe nor Billing Portal cannot be used by customers to to get .pdf invoice or view payment history for one-time payments, and we (website owners) are supposed to internally create/generate .pdf invoices and show payment history?
I mean, for subscriptions we were relying on Billing Portal as there was everything - user could see payment history and get .pdf invoices... but now of one-time payments we need to "develop" our own sections on our website for viewing one-time payments and invoices.

Comment: You could use the `receipt_url` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_url) on related Charge objects which facilitate a PDF download for receipts on one-time purchases.

Comment: Is this still unconfigurable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one time payments are not available in Stripe Customer Portal.  I have been complaining about this to Stripe since they released it. Customer Portal is good for subscriptions but not for customers who make one time payments or subscriptions and one time payments. Also if the first payment is one time,  they cannot upgrade to a subscription in Customer Portal.